# Javascript Retrieve a value from an array for the Cart?

Tags: javascript, events, onclick, cart, handlers

So I have an array that is filled with menu options:

```
var entreescontent=new Array();
entreescontent[0]="Taco Plate";
entreescontent[1]=4.50;
entreescontent[2]="Three tacos of your choice of beef,chicken,pork,or veggie. Served with a side of rice.";

entreescontent[3]="Burrito";
entreescontent[4]=5.50;
entreescontent[5]="Your choice of beef,chicken, pork, or veggie wrapped in a flour tortilla with lettuce, tomato, sour cream, and beans.";

entreescontent[6]="Torta";
entreescontent[7]=4.50;
entreescontent[8]="Your choice of beef,chicken, pork, or veggie in between slices of mexican loaf bread with lettuce, tomato, sour cream, and beans.";

entreescontent[9]="Gorditas";
entreescontent[10]=4.00;
entreescontent[11]="Your choice of beef,chicken, pork, or veggie on top of a corn flour cake with lettuce, tomato, sour cream, and beans.";
```

And when a person clicks on "Entrees" on my navigation bar, this function displays the content on the page:

```
function setCourses(entrees){
    var k=0;
    var element=document.getElementById('contentbody');
    element.innerHTML='';

    while(k<entrees.length){
        var name=entrees[k];
        var space="        $<span>";
        var price=entrees[k+1];
        var break1="</span><br />";
        var break2="<br />";
        var description=entrees[k+2];
        var concat=name+space+price+break1+description+break2+break2;
        element.innerHTML+=concat;
        k+=3;
    }
}
```

And this works with no problem and displays a course like this:

Taco Plate $4.5

Three tacos of your choice of beef,chicken,pork,or veggie. Served with a side of rice.

In my Css i have it so that when the user hovers over the price (which has the span element attached to it) the price changes to a different color.
What I want to do is when person clicks on that price, I want to be able to retrieve that value so I can add it to the Cart, which I have it as a blank :

```
<div id='car'></div>.
```

Using Javascript how can I try to do this?

Comment: You might want to rethink the data structure.

Comment: Why don't you use an object? `[{item:"Taco Plate", cost : 4.5, description : "foo" }, {...}]` also toFixed(2) will be your friend.

Comment: So add click events to the elements which will update the cart.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something quick and dirty

```
    <script>
      var price = 0;
      function add(the_price){
        price =+ the_price;
        //update value
        document.getElementById("car").innerHTML=price;
      }

    </script>

    //from your code
    var space="        $<span onclick='add(" + entrees[k+1] + ")'>";
```

same with minus...